# How to find all the VM process Under KVM hypervisor without login to VM

Tags: qemu, metrics, kvm, hypervisor, nova-hypervisor-show

I need to find out the metrics from all the VM process like cpu usage,memory usage,core, process ,Resource,etc which under KVM hypervisor without login to VM. Please let me know the methods to collect the metrics.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In fact, there are monitoring tools to monitor and gather statistics in real time from the host system. You can use collectd, munin or ganglia.

For more information, check out the link below
[libvirt monitoring](https://libvirt.org/apps.html#monitoring)